# Bugsense returns error: "list index out of range"

Tags: scala, lua, coronasdk, bugsense

I'm currently developing a bugsense plugin for Corona. The function performing the request is:

```
local function sendLog(request) 
    local headers = {}

    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    headers["X-BugSense-Api-Key"] = "XXXXXXXXX"

    local params = {}
    params.headers = headers

    params.body =json.encode(request)

    network.request( "http://www.bugsense.com/api/errors", "POST", networkListener, params)
end
```

The request is executed perfectly, but API returns the following error:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": "list index out of range"
}
```

The petition sent to BUgsense is:

```
{
    "client": {
        "name": "bugsense-ios",
        "version": "0.6"
    },
    "exception": {
        "message": "XXXX",
        "klass": "",
        "where": "",
        "backtrace": "XXXXX"
    },
    "application_environment": {
        "appver": "2.0",
        "uid": "XXXXX",
        "mobile_net_on": "false",
        "phone": "iPad",
        "appname": "app",
        "wifi_on": "false",
        "osver": "10.9"
    }
}
```

Obviously, all the XXXXX are replacing sensitive information.

Could anybody help me on what's wrong in the request to originate that error message?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question for future references

The issue was generated because not all fields were included. All the fields in exception group must be included and non-empty. Even if the instructions from Bugsense are not indicating them as mandatory.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work, but if your stuck it's worth a try:
Try indexing headers with numbers instead of strings.

```
headers[1] = "application/json"
headers[2] = "XXXXXXXXX"
```